# Getting the duration time from date with time in javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to get the duration time in date that has a time.

e.g
start date and time: 2017-07-27 10:31
end date and time: 2017-07-28 15:11

(start date and time) - (end date and time) = total.

after getting the differences it should be convert into time.

Comment: You firstly need to parse the strings to dates, so [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) may apply. Then simply subtract one Date from the other to get the difference in milliseconds and convert to whatever units suit (days, hours, minutes, seconds, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this :

```
const total = a.getTime() - b.getTime()
```

Comment: Perhaps if the OP had Date objects that would work.

Comment: if he has strings , he can use new date object with this string then  do my solution , what you think ?

Comment: Not a good idea. Parsing strings with the built-in parser is not reliable, `new Date("2017-07-27 10:31")` returns an invalid date in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by taking the start time from the end time

```
var startDate = new Date("2017-07-27 10:31");
var endDate = new Date("2017-07-28 15:11");

var durationSeconds = (endDate - startDate) / 1000;
```

From the seconds you can work out the minutes, hours etc.

Comment: Please do not suggest parsing strings with the built–in parser, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results).